# Error when trying to update selections from a pickerinput

Tags: r, shiny

Hello and thanks for the help. I am trying to make an app that updates the selections of one pickerinput depending on the selections of another. The idea is that if one pickerinput has something selected then the other removes all current selections (and vice versa), but I get an error when trying to update the pickerinputs

My code is the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinywidgets)

var1 <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3)
var2 <- c(1,2,3,3,1,2,2,1,2,1)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    pickerInput("primero", 
                "opciones a escoger", 
                choices = var1,
                selected = var1,
                multiple = TRUE
                ),
    pickerInput("segundo", 
                "opciones a escoger 2", 
                choices = var2,
                multiple = TRUE
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    
    
    valor <- reactive({
     c( input$primero)
    })
    
   observeEvent(input$primero,{
     req(valor())
     updatePickerInput(session,"segundo",
                       choices = var2,
                       selected = 
                         if_else(length(valor())>0, NULL, head(var2,1))
                       )
     
   }) 
    
  }
)
```

Error message:

```
Warning: Error in : `false` must be NULL, not a double vector.
  [No stack trace available]
```

Any ideas for suggestions? Thanks a lot

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @r2evans I update the question with the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if_else` requires that the class/type of both its second and third arguments must be the same. Further, since it is intended to be a vectorized logical if/else, having one of them be `NULL` does not make sense.

Looking more at the code, you are using it incorrectly: do not assume that it (or `base::ifelse`) is a drop-in replacement for `if`/`else`, they are very much different. Replace your `observeEvent` with:

```r
   observeEvent(input$primero,{
     req(valor())
     updatePickerInput(session,"segundo",
                       choices = var2,
                       selected =
                         if (!length(valor()) > 0) head(var2, 1)
                       )
     
   })
```

I'm shortcutting it *slightly* here: when we have `if` and no `else`, when the conditional evaluates to `FALSE` then it returns `NULL`, which is what I think your `if_else(length(valor()) > 0, NULL, ..)` meant.